# Inline-block ul li height doesn't fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal navigation using inline-block for li tags as the fowllowing pieces of code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FEATURES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;                                                
 background-color: green;
} 

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
} 

li a {
  display: block;                   
  border: 2px solid #00283a;
  padding: 2.1em 1.5em 2.5em;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/a0odv8tj/2/

- The height of ul tag: 95px;
- The height of li tags: 95.5938px;

But I don't know why the height of the ul tag is not equal the height of the li tags. Could you explain the problem and help me to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/m9k3tasr/. Do you have other CSS rules which are interfering? Check the rules on the element in the DOM Inspector of the console.

Comment: Do you mean the bottom border on the li is outside the ul?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan,  @ Tom Chew-head Millard: Yes, the bottom border on the li is outside the ul. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: So how do you determine height? Seems to be some sort of rounding error to me.

Comment: I checked the supplied jsfiddle and it looks ok, nothing is outside. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @ xxxmatko: There is a little bit difference here. The height of ul tag: 95px and the height of li tags: 95.5938px

Comment: this is why i never use em for padding and margins unless absolutely needed. 2.1em is how you end up with 95.5938

Comment: And how you have measured that values? Clearly it is because the `em`.

Comment: take a look at box-sizing to include border and padding in size calculation. Beside you may like to use display:flex or an older alternative to center text within links http://jsfiddle.net/a0odv8tj/3/

Answer (score 0):

maybe just a hack, but changing

```
padding: 2.1em 1.5em 2.5em;
```

to:

```
padding: 2.0em 1.5em 2.5em;
```

seams to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with line boxes of your text overflowing your anchor element. Your issue is relative to where the baseline for the text is set versus block level elements which collapse to the size of the text.

One way to verify this is to set `overflow:auto;` to `li a` and see how things expand to cover the element.

Re-reading what I wrote, I realize, is not a good explanation but it's been a while since I've thought of the details. I may come back and edit that later.

Or you can read [the spec on this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html) which is probably a good idea.